# How to batch re-deliver SSRS Subscriptions for past days in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012

Our old report server began having issues and we didn't have any redundancy. This server had been set up long before I began working at the company. I set up a new SQL Server instance with SQL Server 2012 (we already had a license, and the old server was still running 2008), upgraded the SSIS packages and deployed both those and the reports. All seems to be running well now, but now we need to get the reports generated and delivered for the days that there was no working report server.

How do I do this? I can't find accurate documentation for the ReportServer Rest API for 2012, and while the reports are available in the Report Manager UI, we both don't know how to email them from there using the subscription and don't want to get all the reports for each day manually because of the potential for human error (wrong date selected, etc).

Comment: Do you have enterprise version or standard for SQL Server?

Comment: Enterprise version